# How to control a RatingBar?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to control a RatingBar, but I'm struggling a bit with that. The problem is that the rating bar doesn't get updated. Here's my code:

```
 Widget _buildBody(videoid) {
    double rating = 3;
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 7, 0, 0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: RatingBarIndicator(
                rating: rating,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      rating=index.toDouble()+1;
                    });
               },
                                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.star,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                ),
                itemCount: 5,
                itemSize: 31.0,
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                letuservoting = true;

                setState(() {
                  rating = 0;
                  israting = false;
                });

                dislike(idovvideo, _rating);
              },
              child: Text(
                "Clear",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I set the rating to 3, and then on Clear text button I want to set it to 0, and then again when the user taps 2, it should show 2 stars. At the moment it only shows these 3 stars no matter what I do. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better not to assign the variable inside the widget because it keeps rebuilding and it will reassign the variable, in your case the `rating` variable will keep reassigning to 3. Try to put it in your class, outside the build method.